# How wait for a async function in an observable?

Tags: angular, caching, promise, observable, ionic5

I'll have an angular service with a function `getTimeLinePosts` to get JSON from a server. In the timeline-page.ts component I'll subscribe to that function. When sending a request to the server I'll need to send the date of the previous cached response (using [ionic cache](https://github.com/Nodonisko/ionic-cache)) to check if there is new data. The problem is the `const date` returns a promise instead of a value. I'll can't use `async getTimeLinePosts` because of the subscribe in de timeline-page.ts. Suggestions how I'll can wait for the date before returning the `loadFromDelayedObservable`?

- timeline-service.ts

```
getTimelinePosts(
    limit: number = 25,
    offset: number = 0,
    type: string = "",
    group: number = null
) {
    let cacheKey = `api/timeline?l=${limit}&o=${offset}&t=${type}&g=${group}`;

    // How wait for this value before fire request
    const date = this.getCachedItem(cacheKey);

    let request = this.http.post(cacheKey, { headers: HEADER.headers , params: JSON.stringify({ dateUpdated: date }) } );
    let groupKey = "timeline";
    let ttl = 60 * 60 * 1;
    let delayType = "none";

    return this.cache
        .loadFromDelayedObservable(url, request, groupKey, ttl, delayType)
        .pipe(map((result) => result));

}
```

```
    async getCachedItem(cacheKey){
        let data = await this.cache.getItem(cacheKey)
        .catch(() => {
            console.log("Oh no! My promise is expired or doesn't exist!");
        });
        return await data.data.dateUpdated;
    }
```

- timeline-page.ts

```
this.TimelineService.getTimelinePosts(limit, offset, type, group).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.setTimelineData(data);
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typical case of combining observables and promises. I'd stick with converting the promise to an observable so we can leverage many of it's advantages.

You could use RxJS `from` function to convert the promise to an observable. Then you could use a higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to map from one observable to another.

Try the following

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getTimelinePosts(
    limit: number = 25,
    offset: number = 0,
    type: string = "",
    group: number = null
) {
    let cacheKey = `api/timeline?l=${limit}&o=${offset}&t=${type}&g=${group}`;

    return from(this.getCachedItem(cacheKey)).pipe(
        switchMap(date => {
            let request = this.http.post(cacheKey, { headers: HEADER.headers, params: JSON.stringify({ dateUpdated: date }) });
            let groupKey = "timeline";
            let ttl = 60 * 60 * 1;
            let delayType = "none";

            return this.cache
                .loadFromDelayedObservable(url, request, groupKey, ttl, delayType)
                .pipe(map((result) => result));
        })
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use observables - specifically mergeMap/flatMap, this is similar to sending a two requests one after the other, where the second one depends on the first:

```
getTimelinePosts(
    limit: number = 25,
    offset: number = 0,
    type: string = "",
    group: number = null
) {
    let cacheKey = `api/timeline?l=${limit}&o=${offset}&t=${type}&g=${group}`;

    this.getCachedItem(cacheKey)
        .pipe(mergeMap((date) => {
            let request = this.http.post(cacheKey, { headers: HEADER.headers , params: JSON.stringify({ dateUpdated: date }) } );
            let groupKey = "timeline";
            let ttl = 60 * 60 * 1;
            let delayType = "none";
        
            return this.cache
                .loadFromDelayedObservable(url, request, groupKey, ttl, delayType)
                .pipe(map((result) => result));
        }));
}
```